# Do Elite Bonuses stack with Overkill Bonuses?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Elite Monsters grants a bonus to XP when defeated. Overkilling an enemy with a Chain Attack also grants an XP bonus. Do Elite Bonuses and Overkill bonuses stack with each other?

[image: Example of an Elite Bonus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comments on Pinckerman’s answer, the Reddit thread didn’t really provide hard evidence whether or not the two XP bonus’ stack. After doing some of my own analysis, I can say for certain the two XP bonus do indeed stack.

First off, I apologize for the poorly taken screenshots, but they at least show enough information. I’m posting them under spoiler tags since there might be some spoilery details because it’s the final story area in the game

Anywho, fighting the same blue elite monster twice in

> Origin,

I compared the results when defeating the monster under normal combat and defeating the monster using chain attack:

- When defeating the monster normally, my units received ~3,200 - ~3,500 experience.
- When defeating the monster during a chain attack, my units received ~14,500 - ~16,500 experience.

My chain attack was roughly 500% XP boost, and 3,200 x 500% is 16,000. So mathematically, the calculations shows that the elite XP bonus and chain attack XP bonus stack

> [image: ~3000 XP]
>  [image: ~14000 XP]

Comment: Thank you for the spoiler warning on those screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently yes.

From [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/whvlzl/we_dont_wanna_kill_them_right/) people are discussing about exploiting chain bonus:

> You can go even higher. Highest I got against an enemy was the final boss. It wasn't quite enough to kill it but by the end of the chain attack my damage ratio was 1459%. I did almost 2.5m damage. But the numbers get even more nuts **if you use them against normal or Elite enemies** and not bosses. I recently had a 1257% damage ratio chain that gave me a 650% experience boost. The final damage total was over 6.7m.

Comment: I'm not sure this entirely answers the question. During chain attacks, it's fairly easy to get 650% EXP boost if you know what you're doing. Unless there is something else mentioned in the reddit thread, I don't see anything quoted that supports chain boosts and elite boosts stacking in the final XP calculation. The quote probably references normal or elite monsters because they are a lot easier to get overkills due to their HP ratios compared to bosses.

Comment: @Wondercricket I don't own the game, so I can't check by myself. But a >1000% boost looked a pretty big number to get only from chain attacks.

Comment: You'd be surprised :) It is a very big number, but definitely possible to achieve with the chain attack alone (as shown [here](https://youtu.be/LGjwUBILsC0?t=1089)).

Comment: @Wondercricket ok that's insane, LOL